# How to unserialize data from Sales_Flat_Order_Payment (additional_information) column to display in custom Grid?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, payment, grid, sales

I am looking for a way to display payment information in a Grid.

I have noticed that there is a column `additional_information` inside `sales_flat_order_payment` table that contains most of the data I need but is serialized.

```
a:10:{s:19:"paypal_ec_create_ba";N;s:8:"CC_BRAND";...
```

The problem is I need to show some of this data in the grid in a filterable way!

Is there a way to unserialize these values?

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to get this data into an eligible format.

I've added a Renderer.php file to my module

```
class Custom_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid_Renderer_Payment extends

Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value = unserialize($row->getData('additional_information'));

        return $value;
    }
}
```

And here is my Grid

```
<?php

class Custom_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sales_flat_order_payment'),
            'parent_id=main_table.entity_id',array('additional_information'));

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('spt'=>'sales_payment_transaction'),
            'spt.transaction_id=main_table.entity_id',array('spt.payment_id', 'spt.txn_id'));

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),
            'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sfo.customer_email',
            'sfo.weight','sfo.discount_description','sfo.increment_id','sfo.store_id',
            'sfo.created_at','sfo.status','sfo.base_grand_total','sfo.grand_total'));

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('ops' => 'ops_alias'),
            'ops.customer_id=main_table.entity_id', array('alias','brand', 'payment_method'));

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _paymentFilter($collection, $column)
    {
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }
        $value = ($column->getFilter()->getValue());
        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
            "sales_flat_order_payment.additional_information like ?"
            , "%$value%");
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('order_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Id'),
            'align' =>'left',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
            'filter_index'=>'sfo.increment_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn("created_at", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("sales")->__("Order Date"),
            "index" => "created_at",
            'filter_index'=>'sfo.created_at',
            "type" => "date",
        ));

        $this->addColumn("billing_name", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("sales")->__("Billing Name"),
            "index" => "billing_name",
        ));

        $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
            'index' => 'customer_email',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.customer_email',
            'width' => '50px',
        ));

        /* Additional Payment Information*/

        $this->addColumn('additional_information', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Information'),
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_paymentFilter'),
            'renderer' => 'Custom_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid_Renderer_Payment'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('payment_id', array(
            'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment ID'),
            'align'         => 'right',
            'index'         => 'payment_id',
            'filter_index' => 'spt.payment_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Total'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'filter_index'=>'sfo.grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'filter_index'=>'sfo.status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'adminhtml/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id'
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
                ));
        }

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }



    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        //return $this->getUrl("*/*/edit", array("id" => $row->getId()));
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current' => true));
    }

}
```

Using the renderer I have been unable to unserialize the data to show in my Grid.php although the data is not being displayed correctly and needs to be separated into it own columns:

```
class Custom_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid_Renderer_Payment extends

Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value = ($row->getData('additional_information'));

        print_r(unserialize($value));
    }
}
```

Data returned in Grid.php

```
 Array ( [paypal_express_checkout_shipping_method] => [paypal_payer_id] =>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue you can solve by customizing the renderer file. You can fetch the format from database by custom query as well.

For eg.
Prodid.php

```
<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Prodid extendsMage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row){
        $url = $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
            'store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'),
            'id'=>$row->getId())
        );
        $exploding = explode('sales_order/edit/id/',$url);
        //print_r($exploding);
        $id = explode('/',$exploding[1]);
        //print_r($id);
        $myId = $id[0];
        //echo $myId;
        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

        // now $write is an instance of Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
        $readresult=$write->query("SELECT product_id FROM `sales_flat_order_item` WHERE `order_id` =$myId "); 
        while ($row = $readresult->fetch() ) {
            $productid = $row['product_id'];
             $myprodid .= $productid.',';

        }
        $myprodid2 = substr($myprodid,0,-1);
            return $myprodid2;
    }

}
?>
```

This will give you the desired result in my case it was product id

Then calling it in the grid file would be like

```
$this->addColumn('ids', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product ID'),
        'width'     => '100px',
        'index'     => 'ids',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Prodid'
    ));
```

The filter=false and sortable false will remove the a href from the headers and will only show you the data.

If you want to make them sortable, then you will need to pass the corresponding unique index id.

Please share if anything is unclear here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');

$order->load(ORDER_ID);

$payment = $order->getPayment();

$info = $payment->getAdditionalInformation();
```

You may need to make use of the following code if info doesn't contain what you're looking for at this point (minus the vardump):

```
$payments = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction')->getCollection()
            ->addPaymentIdFilter($payment->getId());

        foreach ($payments as $itme)
        {
            $addInfo = $item->getAdditionalInformation());
            var_dump($addInfo,true);
        }
```

Comment: Additionally, you can make the information filterable by using the Admin Grid block and modifying it appropriately as well as formatting the data how you need it so it plays nice with filtering.

Comment: thanks for your post and advice, the problem I have it the values stored in the additional_information table is sent back in a hash so its difficult to format into separate fields since it contains "Card Brand", "Last4", "PayPal_ID" etc...

Comment: Show the output of the above code please... Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment extends Mage_Payment_Model_Info... calling getAdditionalInformation is supposed to format the information as an array.

Comment: additionally if this doesn't give you an appropriate array (which it should)... I will come back and explain how to use php to convert that hash into an object or array...

Comment: basically you would take the hash and assign the return of unserialize($hash) to a variable...

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct, I need to unserialze the data to show in an array... please see my edits!

Comment: You're on the right track... since the data doesn't seem to be loading... can you use the second code block I provided in the render function and replace the return value with what you get from $addInfo variable in my block of code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean???

Comment: $payments = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction')->getCollection()
            ->addPaymentIdFilter($row->getPayment()->getId());

        foreach ($payments as $itme)
        {
            $addInfo = $item->getAdditionalInformation());
            $value = $addInfo;
        } return $value; // or some part of value's contents

Comment: Error, `Fatal error: Call to a member function getPayment() on a non-object in`

Comment: Can you please tell me what get_class($row) returns

Comment: `echo get_class($row);` returns `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`

Comment: Ah so... getPayment should work on the sales order model... it sounds like maybe some of your rows aren't of this class possibly... alternatively you can try:

Comment: $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row->getId());

Comment: if($order){ then the foreach, and replace $row->getPayment()->getId() with $order->getPayment()->getId()

Comment: Thankyou, I really appreciate your patients... See my edit. I am still getting an empty "Array" in my Grid

Comment: shoot me an email w/ your skype handle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12176/discussion-between-user2157-and-mprototype)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue with the following solution,

In my Renderer/Payment.php

```
private $_type = 'paymentId';

public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $value = unserialize($row->getData('additional_information'));

    return $value[$this->_type];
}
```

This gets the "Payment ID" value from the additional_information column which is then unserialized in the function.

For the other values that I needed I created files in the Renderer folder

Brand.php

```
private $_type='CC_BRAND';

public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $value = unserialize($row->getData('additional_information'));

    return $value[$this->_type];
}
```

Then in the Grid.php

Add the renderer to the column

```
$this->addColumn('additional_information_brand', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Brand'),
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_paymentFilter'),
    'type' => 'options',
    'options' => array("VISA", "MasterCard"),
    'renderer' => 'Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid_Renderer_Brand'
));
```

And to get the filter

```
  protected function _paymentFilter($collection, $column)
    {
                      case "additional_information_brand":
                {

                    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
                        "sfop.additional_information like ?"
                        , '%CC_BRAND";s:'.strlen($value).':"%'.$value.'%');
                    break;
                }
    }
```

You may want to use a switch for the filters!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying pass a `$key` as parameter for `getAdditionalInformation()`?

Like `getAdditionalInformation('paypal_express_checkout_shipping_method')`
or `getAdditionalInformation($key)`?

Hope u find the solution